# Uso de sleep en python

Tags: python

Se que debo importar `sleep` de `time`:

```
import time
```

o

```
from time import sleep
```

Y que se aplica así:

```
time.sleep(s)
```

pero no sé cómo incluirlo en el resto del codigo.

Comment: Hola, dices que no sabes como incluirlo en el resto del código, ¿puedes mostrar lo que estás intentando hacer?, ¿cuál es ese resto de código del que hablas?

Comment: Muestra el resto de tu código y los mensajes de error que te aparecen. Vas en la dirección correcta, pero necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte apropiadamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

la función sleep pausa la ejecución del hilo sobre el cual es ejecutada, durante el tiempo indicado. por ejemplo, si quiero que "mundo" salga 5 segundos después de "hola". hago un llamado a **timer.sleep(5)**.

```
import time

print "hola"
time.sleep(5)
print "mundo"
```

Comment: Listo, gracias...Igual anoche, antes de ver la respuesta lo logre resolver.